# How to solve an Error with no message in Oracle Adf?

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm receiving an Error with no message on a button click event in Oracle Adf. It's just showing 'Error' and a '-' symbol in the next line. There's nothing much showing in console also. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you invoke a method on that button , or you have some action listener attached to it?
- If you are invoking a method which throws an exception without a message you'll get "Error - " message. If you have such method, try to surround it with try/catch block and make sure you print the stack trace in corresponding catch block.
-If you have button which is  directly bound to a method in a page definition, try to use option (on right click) which converts an action listener to a action which calls a new method in backing bean
- If you have third case, than I suppose  we'll need more details about your button and its properties :)

Regards